# Abstract class method that have multiple parameters type

Tags: dart

I have an abstract class that have a method, but I would like that classes that implement `ImageUploader` use their own parameter like this:

```dart
abstract class ImageUploader {
  Future addImage();
}
```

```dart
class InvoiceUploader implements ImageUploader{
  Future addImage(Invoice invoice){}
}
```

```dart
class CarUploader implements ImageUploader{
  Future addImage(Car car){}
}
```

Is it possible or should I simply not define `addImage()` function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this where I make the parameter to `addImage` generic:

```
abstract class ImageUploader<T> {
  Future addImage(T image);
}

class InvoiceUploader implements ImageUploader<Invoice> {
  Future addImage(Invoice invoice){}
}

class CarUploader implements ImageUploader<Car> {
  Future addImage(Car car){}
}
```